# How to connect Apache Spark with Yarn from the SparkContext?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have developed a Spark application in Java using Eclipse.
So far, I am using the standalone mode by configuring the master's address to 'local[*]'.
Now I want to deploy this application on a Yarn cluster.
The only official documentation I found is http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html

Unlike the documentation for deploying on a mesos cluster or in standalone (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html), there is not any URL to use within SparkContext for the master's adress.
Apparently, I have to use line commands to deploy spark on Yarn.

Do you know if there is a way to configure the master's adress in the SparkContext like the standalone and mesos mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There actually is a URL.

> Ensure that `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` or `YARN_CONF_DIR` points to the directory which contains the (client side) configuration files for the Hadoop cluster. These configs are used to write to HDFS and connect to the YARN ResourceManager

You should have at least `hdfs-site.xml`, `yarn-site.xml`, and `core-site.xml` files that specify all the settings and URLs for the Hadoop cluster you connect to.

Some properties from `yarn-site.xml` include `yarn.nodemanager.hostname` and `yarn.nodemanager.address`.

Since the address has a default of  `${yarn.nodemanager.hostname}:0`, you may only need to set the hostname.

Comment: I am new with this kind of settings, maybe my question is stupid. Do these xml files correspond to **HADOOP_CONF_DIR** and **YARN_CONF_DIR**? Because I don't know what they are. Futhermore, I have to save the xml file inside my java application, right? And Do you have an example for these files ? Finally, How do i call these xml file in my java code in order to get the settings for execution.. Sorry if my questions seem stupid

Comment: I don't know how you installed hadoop, but if someone else did, you should get in contact with them. Yes, you'll need the XML files on the client machine running Spark. They do not have to be in the Java app directly. Examples for these files can be found online if you search for them, or again, ask the person responsible for the Hadoop cluster.

Comment: And those two "settings" are environment variables, which the Spark driver picks up. The XML files are within those folders. No extra config should be needed other than `--master yarn`.

Comment: Actually, I am alone in this project. Last question, where do I have to execute the following command to run my spark application '**./bin/spark-submit --class path.to.your.Class --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster [options] <app jar> [app options]**' ? in the masterNode of my Hadoop cluster ?

Comment: Again, I don't know how your installed Spark, but you should be able to run on any node with the Spark client binaries. I think the latest packages of Hortonworks and Cloudera quickstart VMs come with Spark already installed and configured for YARN, by the way, if you just wanted to go that route